# Summing up column values in python using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
a   b  
1   5   
1   1
2   4
1   3
2   1
```

I want to sum up 1's in `a` column and 1's in `b` column and use this sum as number of size in bubble plot. How should I do it? Numbers are in range 1-5 and I have to do it for all possibilities for ex. 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,5 and do something like that also for 2,3,4,5. Of course I`m importing much bigger set of data from Excel.

Comment: Could you show us an attempt that you made in order to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many rows are 1,1; how many are 1,2; ...; how many are 5,5, then groupby is going to be your friend.

```py
df.groupby(['a','b']).count()
```

Comment: How do I do it if i have free columns? I have to do correlation between a c and b c.